# Concurrent HashMap default segment value?

Tags: java, collections

What is the default number of segments in a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in Java?

How does it affect the concurrent performance of the data structure?

Can I customize the number of segments, and if so, how do I choose the right value for my specific application?

Comment: What do you mean by “segments”? The constructors let you specify an initial capacity and a load factor, as well as a hint of expected number of threads.

Comment: did you try to read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

That `ConcurrentHashMap` uses segments is merely an implementation details for Java versions from 1.5 (when `ConcurrentHashMap` was introduced) to 1.7 (which is the last version that used segments).

In Java versions 1.8 and later `ConcurrentHashMap` no longer uses a segments in its implementation.

For reference, the Java 1.7 version of `ConcurrentHashMap` is available
at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk7u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java with the inner class `Segment` at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk7u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L350

The Java 1.8 version of `ConcurrentHashMap` is available at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java and contains an implementation note about the segments (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L481):

> Maintaining API and serialization compatibility with previous versions of this class introduces several oddities. Mainly: We leave untouched but unused constructor arguments refering to concurrencyLevel. We accept a loadFactor constructor argument, but apply it only to initial table capacity (which is the only time that we can guarantee to honor it.) We also declare an unused "Segment" class that is instantiated in minimal form only when serializing.